# Is there an enum data type for resource actions in the aws cdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-cdk

When adding policy statements for a resource, it would be helpful to be able to reference a defined action.

Like "sqs:SendMessage" rather than having to hard code that string myself.

Does the `AWS CDK` have classes/enums like that available for each services actions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are classes/enums in [`CDK`](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/)

E.g., the only `SQS` class is [QueueBase](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-sqs.QueueBase.html)

`SQS` enums are:

- [DeduplicationScope](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-sqs.DeduplicationScope.html)
- [FifoThroughputLimit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-sqs.FifoThroughputLimit.html)
- [QueueEncryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-sqs.QueueEncryption.html)

Comment: Yes there are enums for the SQS class, but not for the policy actions for an SQS queue, like SendMessage, ReceiveMessage, etc

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, agreed.